# How understand in which logic a sequent is provable and in which one is not?

Tags: logic, sequent-calculus

Determine if the following sequent is provable in the classic logic, intuitionistic logic or minimal logic.
$$ ( \exists x \psi(x) \rightarrow \forall x \theta(x) ) \vdash \forall x ( \psi(x) \rightarrow \theta(x) ) $$
Where $ \psi, \theta$ are two formula such that the only free variable is $x$.
I can't use $\forall R$ to go up because $ \psi(x) \rightarrow \theta(x) $ possesses a free variable. I have no idea how to do it.
Anyway how do understand in which logic is provable and in which one is not?

Comment: Which tools have been introduced in your course for showing that a certain sequent is not provable?

Comment: Model of Kripke for minimal and intuitionistic logic.

Comment: Well, then you just try to prove it step by step in a sequent calculus. And if it seems like you can't, look for a counterexample in the form of a Kripke model. It is useful to work backwards. How do you prove a sequent of the form $\Gamma \vdash \forall x ~ \varphi$? Then, how do you prove a sequent of the for $\Gamma \vdash \psi \rightarrow \theta$? Etc. until you either find a proof or are convinced that one does not exist.

Comment: Yes, but for $ \Gamma \vdash \forall x \varphi $ you are supposing that $\varphi$ does not contain free variable, here i have a free variable...

Comment: No, that's not what the restriction on this rule says. The restriction states that you may infer $\Gamma \vdash \forall x ~ \varphi$ from $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$ provided that $x$ is not free in $\Gamma$.

Comment: Still $x$ is not free in $ \Gamma $

Comment: I think i make confusion between the terminology of free and bound variable .

Answer (score 0):

I try to answer my own question since I think i get how to prove it (at least in classic logic)

$$ \vdash \exists x \psi(x), \forall x( \psi(x) \rightarrow \theta(x) ; \forall x \theta(x) \vdash \forall x( \psi(x) \rightarrow \theta(x)  $$
$$ \text{---------------------------------------------------  } \rightarrow L $$
$$ (\exists x \psi(x) \rightarrow \forall x \theta(x)) \vdash \forall x( \psi(x) \rightarrow \theta(x) $$

then for

$$ \text{--------------------------------------------------- axiom }  $$
$$ \psi \vdash \psi $$
$$ \text{---------------------------------------------------  } P $$
$$ \psi \vdash \psi, \theta $$
$$ \text{---------------------------------------------------  }  \rightarrow R $$
$$ \vdash \psi, \psi \rightarrow \theta $$
$$ \text{---------------------------------------------------  } L \exists , L \forall  $$
$$ \vdash \exists x \psi(x), \forall x( \psi(x) \rightarrow \theta(x)$$
and for
$$ \text{--------------------------------------------------- axiom }  $$
$$ \theta \vdash \theta $$
$$ \text{---------------------------------------------------  } P $$
$$ \theta, \psi \vdash \theta $$
$$ \text{---------------------------------------------------  } R \rightarrow  $$
$$ \theta \vdash \psi \rightarrow \theta $$
$$ \text{---------------------------------------------------  } R \forall  $$
$$ \theta(t) \vdash \forall x( \psi(x) \rightarrow \theta(x) $$
$$ \text{---------------------------------------------------  } R \forall  $$
$$ \forall x \theta(x) \vdash \forall x( \psi(x) \rightarrow \theta(x) $$

Hence it is prouvable in the classic logic. And since I don't think there exist a prove in sequent calculus with less than 1 right rule used then it is not provable in the intuitionistic logic, a fortiori in the minimal.

Comment: Firstly, the inference from "I don't think there exists a proof" to "it is not provable" is not valid. Secondly, you are proving the sequent in a valid but rather roundabout way. Instead, you should ask yourself: how do you prove a sequent of the form $\Gamma \vdash \psi \rightarrow \theta$?

Comment: (The point being that if you prove this in a more natural way, you might see that this can also be proved in intuitionistic logic.)

Comment: Yeah... the point is that I'm an idiot :) the variable $x$ is not free, so I can apply the rule that I wanted to apply